# Do I really need all vendors composer installs for the first time?

Tags: php, composer-php, ratchet

I am new to web app development and pre existing frameworks for PHP development online. I just downloaded composer so that I can install ratchet for my socket programming. Composer automatically installed few other vendors like **evenement,guzzle,react symfony and composer itself as well**. I have briefly come across all of them when I was researching  and they appear to me as independent frameworks.

My question is , are they installed as a dependency to ratchet or they are just free goodies which always comes when you install something using composer ? Will it make any difference if I will delete everything from vendor except ratchet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those pakages are installed because `Ratchet` needs them. If you look at [Ratchet composer.json file](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/blob/master/composer.json) you will see dependencies here:

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9"
      , "react/socket": "^0.3 || ^0.4"
      , "guzzle/http": "^3.6"
      , "symfony/http-foundation": "^2.2"
      , "symfony/routing": "^2.2"
    }
```

and they need to be installed to make Ratchet work. Also those packages might have own dependencies, for example `symfony/routing` might need other packages and so on so everything that is installed in this case is needed.

Comment: Great ! Thanks heaps for your help.